# Remotely modify OpenVMS file using vim and SFTP from a Linux system

Tags: vim, sftp, scp, openvms

I'm using CentOS 5.5 and I'm trying to remotely modify file of an OpenVMS server. I tried with scp but I got an error about an "unexpected newline".

I tried to find the solution to this but I haven't found it yet.

Then I tried with sftp and I succeded but only in my openvms home directory. I don't know how to reach other folders.

For example :

vim sftp://myLogin@myServer//sys\$user/myLogin/test.txt

will successfully open the file test.txt in my openvms home directory.

What I would like to achieve is to modify the file test.txt in this directory for example : OpenVMSHomeDirectory.xxx.yyy

Does anybody know a way to do this ? I fail to find how to reach my file to edit it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSH sftp client that you are probably using supports the quite Unix centric version 3 of the protocol. Try with a client supporting a later version as lftp, WinSCP or FileZilla.

If I recall correctly, OpenVMS SFTP server converts the VMS file paths into some more Unix friendly format (i.e. using / as the directory separator) when talking to a v3 client.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to add my path with '/' and see if it works. :) I cannot test right now.